# Facebook Oauth Failed and Give error This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings auth.expo.io

Tags: react-native, facebook, oauth, expo, expo-go

I use expo-go and I use auth-session (Deprecated) method
in app.js file I am able to open login window of facebook but after entering creds it (maybe) redirected to expo.auth.io page and it contains
`This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.`

i add Valid `OAuth Redirect URIs : https://auth.expo.io/@dileeshabilash/Demo_main` correctly
but I dummy data in add platform in Facebook dev

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Button, Text } from 'react-native';
import * as Facebook from 'expo-auth-session/providers/facebook';
import { useMutation, QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from 'react-query';

const FACEBOOK_APP_ID = 'ID'; // Replace with your actual Facebook App ID
const REDIRECT_URI = 'https://auth.expo.io/@dileeshabilash/Demo_main'; // Replace with your actual redirect URI

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <FacebookAuthScreen />
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}

function FacebookAuthScreen() {
  const [, , promptAsync] = Facebook.useAuthRequest({
    clientId: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    redirectUri: REDIRECT_URI,
  });

  const facebookRegister = useMutation(async () => {
    const result = await promptAsync();

    if (result.type === 'success') {
      const { access_token } = result.params;
      console.log(access_token);
    } else {
      console.log(result);
      console.log("Authentication failed");
    }
  });

  const handleFacebookLogin = () => {
    facebookRegister.mutate();
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>{REDIRECT_URI}</Text>
      <Button title="Login with Facebook" onPress={handleFacebookLogin} />
    </View>
  );
}
```